# NoReverseMatch Django Postman

Tags: django, django-urls, django-1.4

Why does this return a `NoReverseMatch`?

From [django-postman](https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/src/6ff9fdf9c33f7365a7235a789af2e47f47d9c4fa/postman/urls.py?at=default):

```
url(r'^write/(?:(?P<recipients>[\w.@+-:]+)/)?$', 'write', name='postman_write'),
```

Template:

```
<a href='{% url postman_write recipients=object.user %}'>Send Message</a>
```

This does not work either..

```
<a href='{% url postman_write object.user %}'>Send Message</a>
```

Returns: `Reverse for 'postman_write' with arguments '(<User: admin>,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.` What am I missing to construct this url properly? Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm it works with no arguments passed - just `{% url postman_write %}`. According to the view code, it should default recipients to `None` with no parameter passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing a user object in `url` tag. You need to pass the username.

```
{% url postman_write recipients=object.user.username %}
```

Also make sure you have included the postman urls in your main `urls.py` file.

Comment: Thanks, but still NoReverseMatch: `Reverse for 'postman_write' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'recipients': u'admin'}' not found.`

Comment: @NickB i have updated the answer try to pass email of user and let me know

Comment: Still NoReverseMatch: `Reverse for 'postman_write' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'recipients': u'admin@mysite.com'}' not found.`

Comment: have you inluded the postman urls in your main url file? (also recipients takes colon separated username)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`{% url postman_write object.user.username %}`